# Why block number is kept BigInteger in Web3j?

Tags: web3j

```
BigInteger blockNum = web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, false).send()
    .getBlock().getNumber();
```

`Long.MAX_VALUE` (9223372036854775807) is more than enough to hold block number.

It is easier and efficient to iterate over long than BigInteger. There are use-cases when we need to iterate over blocks; for example - to find N latest blocks.

Also addition, deletion and comparison is easier with long.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, using a 'long' would be more efficient to store a value such as *block number*.

In fact, if you look at Ethereumj (Java implementation of Ethereum protocol)  you'll see that they have used 'long' to represent the block number in the [BlockHeader](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/2ed0862e999c5415d4935549ff0cff1dfc738c31/ethereumj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/core/BlockHeader.java) class.

```
/* A scalar value equal to the number of ancestor blocks.
* The genesis block has a number of zero */
private long number;
```

Web3j [EthBlock](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/958ad9819e29a08cf0ef2b7263b64618df740dc2/core/src/main/java/org/web3j/protocol/core/methods/response/EthBlock.java) class stores the block number as a string and converts it to a BigInteger when needed. My only idea of why their using this method is because of some of the operations their performing in [JsonRpc2_0Rx](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/b420cddc5dff5213f4d39f87482b1d2b199f9e08/core/src/main/java/org/web3j/protocol/rx/JsonRpc2_0Rx.java). They seem to be very specific so that they can successfully communicate with the Geth node.

I agree with you, long should be used for many reasons. Perhaps it's worth asking the Web3j team on their [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/web3j/web3j)?

Comment: @dev ツ I've just notice that you already posted in their gitter. Let me know how it goes 

Comment: Yes, I am waiting for a reply from any of the core team member.